# predicative and attributive adjectives?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-language

I'm reading Peter Geach's *Good and Evil*, and am struggling to understand what predicative and attributive adjectives mean, the significance of the words and how they be applied to good and bad.

Answer (score 3):

See examples at the very beginning of [Geach's essay (1956)](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Emthompso/readings/geach2.pdf).

It is a *grammatical* distinction: a "small elephant" is not something that is an elephant and is small because elephants are big (speaking absolutely). A small elephant is small only relative to the elephants kind.

See [Intrinsic vs. Extrinsic Value](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/value-intrinsic-extrinsic/) :

> Peter Geach (1956) argues that [G.E.Moore](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moore/) [in [*Principia Ethica* (1903)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moore-moral/) and elsewhere, Moore embraces the consequentialist view that whether an action is morally right or wrong turns exclusively on whether its consequences are intrinsically better than those of its alternatives] makes a serious mistake when comparing “good” with “yellow.” Moore says that both terms express unanalyzable concepts but are to be distinguished in that, whereas the latter refers to a natural property, the former refers to a nonnatural one. Geach contends that there is a mistaken assimilation underlying Moore’s remarks, since “good” in fact operates in a way quite unlike that of “yellow”—something that Moore wholly overlooks.
>
> This contention would appear to be confirmed by the observation that the phrase “x is a yellow bird” splits up logically (as Geach puts it) into the phrase “x is a bird and x is yellow,” whereas the phrase “x is a good singer” does not split up in the same way. Also, from “x is a yellow bird” and “a bird is an animal” we do not hesitate to infer “x is a yellow animal,” whereas no similar inference seems warranted in the case of “x is a good singer” and “a singer is a person.”
>
> > On the basis of these observations Geach concludes that nothing can be good in the free-standing way that Moore alleges; rather, whatever is good is good relative to a certain kind.

Answer (score 0):

Just an add-on to Mauro's answer. Left to myself I'd say that 'predicative'/ 'attributive' is both a linguistic and a logical distinction:

## Predicative and attributive

> For Geach ...surface grammar is no sure guide to
> the attributive/predicative distinction. He says,
> I shall say that in a phrase 'an AB' ('A' being an adjective and 'B' being a
> noun) 'A' is a (logically) predicative adjective if the predication 'is an AB'
> splits up logically into a pair of predications 'is a B' and 'is A'; otherwise
> I shall say that 'A' is a (logically) attributive adjective (op. cit., p. 33).
> 'Big', 'small', 'forged' and 'putative' are his examples of logically
> attributive adjectives since 'x is a big flea' does not split up logically
> into 'x is a flea' and 'x is big', 'x is a small elephant' does not split up
> logically into 'x is an elephant' and 'x is small', 'x is a forged banknote'
> does not split up logically into 'x is a banknote' and 'x is forged', and 'x
> is the putative father of y' does not split up logically into 'x is the father
> of y' and 'x is putative'. 'Red' and 'sweet' are his examples of logically
> predicative adjectives since 'x is a red book' does split up logically into
> 'x is a book' and 'x is red', and, presumably, 'x is a sweet apple' does
> split up logically into 'x is an apple' and 'x is sweet'. Thus although
> 'small' in 'Dumbo is small' is grammatically predicative, it is logically
> attributive, and although 'red' in 'x is a red book' is grammatically
> attributive, it is logically predicative. (Alfred F. MacKay, 'Attributive-Predicative', Analysis, Vol. 30, No. 4 (Mar., 1970), pp. 113-120: 115; references to Geach are to  P. T. Geach, 'Good and Evil', ANALYSIS, Vol. 17, December, 1956, pp. 33-4.)

Geach tries to show that 'good' is always an attributive adjective:

> For 'good' the point is not so clear at first sight, since 'good' is not
> *alienans* [GT - see below] - whatever holds true of an A as such holds true of a good A.
> But consider the contrast in such a pair of phrases as 'red car' and 'good
> car'. I could ascertain that a distant object is a red car because I can see
> it is red and a keener-sighted but colour-blind friend can see it is a car;
> there is no such possibility of ascertaining that a thing is a good car by
> pooling independent information that it is good and that it is a car. This
> sort of example shows that 'good' like 'bad' is essentially an attributive
> adjective (op. cit., pp. 33-4).

There is no space to discuss the point here.

***Alienans***

'Putative' in 'putative father' is *alienans*, since a 'putative
father' is not both a father and putative. Indeed the point of the 'putative' is
that he may not be a father at all. (Charles R. Pigden, Geach on 'Good', The Philosophical Quarterly (1950-), Vol. 40, No. 159 (Apr., 1990), pp. 129-154: 131.)